# ZF + Doctrine - own localization of models folder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I started to develop new application, it's my first application written in ZF2. I have some experience about making application with ZF1 with Doctrine1, but now I would like to do application with using ZF2 and Doctrine2.
Default entities folder is in the module directory. I would like to have one models folder, which is shared in whole application. So I've prepared application structure like this:

```
config
models
 generated
module
 Administration
 Application
public
vendor
```

I have designed database (MySQL) and imported it to XML form, using Doctrine CLI. I've generated also models. But now I have problem - how to use it in my modules? I've prepared some code:

```
protected $em;

public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getEntityManager()
{
    if (null === $this->em) {
        $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }
    return $this->em;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'carriers' => $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Carrier')->findAll()
    ));
}
```

And I've got an error 'Class Carrier not found'. It is a problem with paths, but I'm totally newbie in ZF2 and I've no idea how to configure it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the path to Doctrine 2's entities within configuration. Now i assume you have a configuration somewhere similar to this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Basically what you have to do is to Map the paths correctly. Within the `orm_defaults` you can define the driver for each module separately, or just use a global driver.

Within `__NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'` you define a driver with the given name and also define where exactly the entities get stored. In your case this would probably be something like

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Administration/Entity')
```

Or whatever your Module is named where your entities are stored. In this case `Administration`

Additionally, always assign the fully qualified repository name like this:

```
->getRepository('NAMESPACE\Entity\Carrier')
```

Comment: I've put this code to my module/Application/config/module.config.php:
 
 'doctrine' => array(
     'orm_autoload_annotations' => true,
     'driver' => array(
         __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
             'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver',
             'cache' => 'array',
             'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../../../models')
         ),
         'orm_default' => array(
             'drivers' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
             )
         )
     )

but still I've got the error as above.

Comment: Please see updated answer, error probably was just the wrong method to call the repository

Comment: unfortunately, I've got still the same error (only difference is name of class in the error message)

Comment: Well, the error tells you that the class is not to be found, so it has to do something with either path's or unset `namespace X` declaration inside your model files :S

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working. I've checked in config file, if file exists (using var_dump and file_exists). I've tried to add namespace to model file, also tried without it, tried to get repository with Application\Entity\Carrier and also only Carrier - still the same error. Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: solved. After a lot of time, changing some configuration options finally it works. But I don't know why :-)

Comment: Was it within the scope i suggested or something different? Would be nice to know for future occurences

Comment: in Module configuration I've added a ClassLoader object to load Entities with the appropriate path.